# Converting BMap<BString, Object> to Java Class in Ballerina

Tags: interop, ballerina

I'm working on a project in Ballerina and I need to convert a `BMap<BString, Object>` to a Java class.

Additionally, I have a Java function that returns a Ballerina record object of type `BMap<BString, Object>`, and I want to use this function in another Java function and access the fields of the record.

I'm looking for guidance on how to perform the conversion and access the fields of the Ballerina record in Java.

Answer (score 0):

In Ballerina, records are represented in Java(runtime) as a `BMap<BString, Object>`, where the keys represent the field names, and the values represent the field values. You can access the field values by using the field names as keys to the `BMap`. Here's a Java code snippet that demonstrates how to access the field values of a Ballerina record:

```php
import io.ballerina.runtime.api.values.BMap;
import io.ballerina.runtime.api.values.BString;

public class GetFieldValues {
    public static Object getFieldValue(BString key, BMap<BString, Object> recordValue) {
        return recordValue.get(key);
    }
}
```

In the code above, we have a Java class `GetFieldValues` with a method `getFieldValue`, that takes a `BString` representing the field name and a `BMap<BString, Object>` representing the Ballerina record. It returns the field value associated with the given field name.

You can use this method to access the fields of your Ballerina record in Java by passing the field name as a `BString`.